# React: Composite components vs DOM components

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between a "composite component" and a "DOM component" in react?

The official docs contrasts the two terms to each other in a few places, but never really explains them. Eg:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html

From react 0.14 a few of test utils methods, like findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass no longer takes "DOM components".

Comment: Aren't just DOM components those that are already exist, such as `<div>`, `<input>` etc. and  composite components are those that you define yourself, <Mycomponent /> and other components consisting of compositions of components?

Comment: Not sure, that's why I'm asking:) Just found this article (http://www.mattzabriskie.com/blog/react-referencing-dynamic-children) which implies that a "composite component" simply is a component made up of multiple components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is clearly defined in the [test-utils page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#isdomcomponent). So DOM component is really a plain div or a span. Unlike a CompositeComponent that can be a div, but created but by the React.createClass().