# What are DOM components in the context of refs in react Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the legacy react documentation for [ref forwarding](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components), there's a note which says:

> Ref forwarding is not limited to **DOM components**. You can forward refs to **class component** instances, too.

In another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34199605/3429430) it is suggested that *DOM components* are those which return a single(non-nested) dom element. E.g.

```
function FancyButton(props) {
  return (
    <button className="FancyButton">
      //no further child elements
      //which means not even {props.children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

My doubt is that these *plain-single-non-nested(leaf element?)* elements can be represented as class components as well, so if react docs mean this as the DOM component, then why would it say *You can forward refs to class component instances, too*?

To me it feels like react docs meant to say

> ref forwarding is not limited to **function components**. You can forward refs to **class component** instances, too.

Comment: Good question. At a first glance this question looks very basic _(like you might have confused React components with DOM elements)_, which is probably why somebody voted it down. Only after reading it carefully and following the links _(which one should do)_ I understood the problem, i.e. that the (legacy ?) React docs actually use the term __"DOM components"__, and not only as a synonym for anything like _DOM elements_ or _React components_ or something.

Comment: I don't offer this as an answer because I don't think this term is defined anywhere and I can't know for sure, but as someone who has developed with React for a few years, I'm pretty certain what the legacy docs mean by "DOM components" is any JSX element that represents a DOM element rather than another React component built on top of them. I don't agree with the suggestion that nothing can be nested, nesting isn't relevant at all because that only relates to children, which are part of props, not the "component" itself.

Comment: What are you actually blocked on though? This is just about documentation? Run the code, see what happens. Rinse and repeat until you have an understanding.

Comment: @morganney To be honest, I am not blocked on this topic, I have moved onto reading further articles. It's just a conceptual question. I think I better put this on react github repo as a question.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the term "DOM component" can be ambiguous, and there is some overlap between the concept of a DOM component and a React tree leaf node.

A DOM component, in general, is any component that renders an actual HTML element on the page. Both function components that return a single non-nested element and class components that render one or more elements are included.

In the context of **ref forwarding**, the React documentation is specifically referring to components that render an **actual HTML element**, whether they are implemented as function components or class components. Ref forwarding allows you to pass a ref from a parent component to an underlying child component so that you can interact with its underlying DOM node directly.

So when the documentation says "**Ref forwarding is not limited to DOM components. You can forward refs to class component instances, too**", it means that you can forward refs from **parent components to child class components** that render actual HTML elements.

In summary, while there may be some ambiguity in the term "DOM component", in this context it refers specifically to components that render actual HTML elements and can include both function and class components.

Comment: Likely ChatGPT I think

Comment: I would like to take my upvote back, after reading @DavidW's comment I re-read the answer carefully. The last two paragraphs don't answer the actual question. It says _... DOM component can include both function and class components._ then this begs the same question again why would the docs say _Ref forwarding is not limited to DOM components(both func and class). You can forward refs to class component instances, too_.

Comment: _Both function components that return a single non-nested element..._ What about function components that return _nested elements_? Sounds like chat gpt copy pasted `single non nested` from the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Ref forwarding is not limited to **DOM components**. You can forward refs
> to **class component instances**, too.

So , basically here the focus should not be on the `class component` , it should be on the `class component instances`.

Basically, as stated by @Shivanshu in his answer , we can use refs in the HTML elements referred to as DOM Components directly or we can further forward it to the child components either it is a functional component or class component.

As per my understanding ,here the mention of `class component instances` is there because if we forward refs to class components , they are to be accessed using the `instance of the class` with `this` keyword.

```
class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <input
            value={this.props.value}
            onChange={this.props.onChange}
            ref={this.props.innerRef}
          />
        );
      }
    }

    

   const Input = React.forwardRef(function (props, ref) {
           return <ClassComponent {...props} innerRef={ref} />;
   });
```

Comment: I am bit unsure about _we can use refs in the HTML elements referred to as DOM Components directly_.

Comment: **We can use refs in the HTML elements referred to as DOM Components directly** means  if we return **HTML elements** instead of returning any **Component (function or class)** in the forwardRef and pass the ref directly to those elements. Since DOM components are HTML elements only <https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#isdomcomponent> I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: That is not what react docs say, this is what the other answer-er mentions, which I don't think is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I am starting to think that actually from the context of  [Forwarding refs to dom components](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components) article, they use **function components synonymously with DOM components**.

Even furthermore, it sounds like they are thinking of [leaf components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65278426/3429430) as a subset of function components, although this is an ambiguous statement as they never define leaf components and you can create a leaf component based upon a class component as well. Any way in the ref forwarding article they mention:

> Although such encapsulation is desirable for application-level components like FeedStory or Comment, it can be inconvenient for highly reusable “leaf” components like FancyButton[**certainly function component**] or MyTextInput.

Also leaf components can have nested structures of pure dom elements, it's just they can't have further react components as child(ren)

Now the first line of the article itself is

> Consider a **FancyButton component** that renders the native button DOM element

Here `FancyButton` is a stateless<sup>1</sup> function component, .

I would take it as:

> Consider a **FancyButton component[Dom/leaf component]** that renders the native button DOM-element.

Then as the article progresses, they show how to forward ref on a function component as:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```

Come to think of it! The title of the article is *Forwarding refs to DOM components* and then in the article they talk about *function components* and give an example of how to forward a ref to a function component. Most likely they are taking DOM component as a simple function component(leaf like?). So I would interpret the note as following:

> ref forwarding is not limited to DOM components **[simple leaf like function components]**. You can forward refs to **[complex non leaf like nested]** class component instances, too.

---

<sup>1:  Up until that point in the legacy docs, they didn't have hooks, so they were considering functional components stateless.</sup>